# The result of ObjectStore.get() of Indexeddb is underfined in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, indexeddb

I have an application that uses indexeddb. 
I was developing on Windows and was testing with Chrome. Everything works fine in Chrome. But When I tested it with Safari on Mac Book it fails.

The part of the code that Safari (version 7.1.3) fails, but not Chrome:

```
var request = indexedDB.open("db", 1);

    request.onsuccess = function() {
        var db = this.result;   
        var tx = db.transaction ("store", "readonly");
        var store = tx.objectStore("store");

        var item = store.get(localId); //it is provided;

        item.onsuccess= function () {

            var data = item.result; // the result is underfined, as well as data
            console.log("Krippe is: " + data.krippe); //fails here; 
            if (data){

                console.log("IInstitution.krippe = " + data.krippe);
                DisplayValue = data.krippe;     
            }
            initPage();
        };

        item.onerror = function () {
            console.log("Error: " + item.result.errorCode);
        }

    }
```

I used the debugger in Safari, and the

```
    item.onsuccess()
```

is actually fired and it gets into the function. But the

```
    item.result
```

is undefined only in Safari. In Chrome it works perfectly fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? And how to fix it?

Best

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac to test on, but I'll venture to guess that it's yet another IndexedDB bug in Safari. Many have been reported.

This one could have slipped under the radar because not many people use the API like that. I used IndexedDB for years without knowing about the result being put back on the request object until [this](https://github.com/dumbmatter/IndexedDB-getAll-shim/pull/1). Instead, most people access the result of a request like this:

```
        item.onsuccess= function (event) {
            var data = event.target.result;
```

That will probably work in Safari, but beware that there are tons of other IndexedDB bugs in Safari too.

Comment: I will try this. Can you please link me the known issues on Safari, so that I could anticipate it?

Comment: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/9/25/IndexedDB-on-iOS-8--Broken-Bad describes some but there are more. It's pretty bad.

Comment: I have tried the above solution. No changes. The result is still undefined. and therefor the data. Any ideas?